# display two columns from rows in a multidimensional array in listview - android

Tags: java, android, matrix, cursor

I've been trolling for some time now trying to find a way to implement this but have come up dry. Let me state that I am fairly new to java/android development so please be gentle.

What I have is a multidimensional array giving info about a store location like so

```
static final String[][] coordinates = new String[][] {
    {"1","location_name", "managername","geo:geolocation?z=10" },
    {"2","location_name","managername","geo:geolocation?z=10" },
    {"3","location_name","managername","geo:geolocation?z=10" },
    {"4","location_name","managername","geo:geolocation?z=10" }
```

};

What I am trying to do is just pull the LOCATION_NAME and MANAGERNAME from the array per row, and display it in a list view using the layout xml described here, http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-1.html.

I was reading that it might be best to use the matrix cursor to implement this, but as being new to java development, i'm a bit confused as to how I'd go about doing this.

Anyone have any ideas that can guide me in the right direction?

Thanks, Ryan

EDIT: I should note, I decided to change to a simpler method of implemenation... as least for now. NOW, I am using just two single dimension arrays, one for LOCATION_NAME and one for MANAGER_NAME. I am using the 2 row layout described in the link. Where I am running into a snag is in the IconicAdapter. How to I fill both (inner) rows of each row with a separate string? This is what I have, which i know is wrong.

```
class IconicAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
   IconicAdapter(){
       super(about.this, R.layout.about_layout, R.id.title, locations);
       super(about.this, R.layout.about_layout, R.id.secondLine, managers);
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to subclass `ArrayAdapter` and override `getView()`. [Here is a free excerpt](http://commonsware.com/Android/excerpt.pdf) from one of my books that covers how this is done.

Comment: thank you Commonsware. Any other ideas regarding my edited request? Is there a way I can inflate the rows similar to what I have above?

Comment: @dubchamp: "I decided to change to a simpler method of implemenation" -- no, you chose a more complex approach. "Is there a way I can inflate the rows similar to what I have above?" -- no.

Comment: i kept the first line inflated in the Iconic adapter class. Then I changed the getView to below, and I can load the second line no problamo with the second array 

@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
     
     
     View row=super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
     ImageView icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.icon);
     icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);

     
     
     TextView tv2 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.secondLine);
     tv2.setText("Manager: " + managers[position]);


     return(row);
    }